# What is the correct syntax for this data.table task in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table` in `R`:

```
  library(data.table)
  DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=sample(rnorm(9)), v=1:9)
```

I just want to compute the minimum and the maximum by the column `x` and add these two new columns to `DT`. Here is my line for this:

```
  DT[,c("e","d"):= list(min(y),max(y)), with=FALSE, by = x] 
  Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(c("e", "d"), list(min(y), max(y))),  : 
  'with' must be TRUE when 'by' or 'keyby' is provided
```

Nonetheless, if I write: `DT[,c("e","d"):= list(min(y),max(y)), with=FALSE]`, I get this:

```
     x       y    v     e       d
  1: a -1.7125000 4 -1.7125 1.30553
  2: a  1.0198038 5 -1.7125 1.30553
  3: a  1.3055301 6 -1.7125 1.30553
  4: b -0.9238759 1 -1.7125 1.30553
  5: b  0.3077016 2 -1.7125 1.30553
  6: b -1.2580845 3 -1.7125 1.30553
  7: c -0.9399120 7 -1.7125 1.30553
  8: c -0.1910583 8 -1.7125 1.30553
  9: c  0.1239158 9 -1.7125 1.30553
```

As you can see, this is working but it's not doing the task by `x`. I want to obtain something similar but `e` and `d` are supposed to be computed by each value of the variable `x`. So, my question is: How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"`:=` by group" (new in version 1.8.2) and "`:=` with multiple new columns" (new in version 1.7.8) are both relatively recent additions to **data.table**.

"`:=` by group *with multiple new columns*" just hasn't (yet) been implemented.

So for now, you can either do this (if you want a one-liner):

```
setkey(DT, "x")
DT <- DT[DT[,list(e=min(y), d=max(y)), by=key(DT)]]
```

or this (if you want to minimize extra copying operations):

```
setkey(DT, "x")
DT[,e:=min(y), by=key(DT)]
DT[,d:=max(y), by=key(DT)]
```

Comment: `DT[,e:=min(y), by = x][,d:=max(y), by = x]` is an alternative one-liner solution. This does not require keys being set

Comment: All correct here. For completeness the to do items are: [FR#1710](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1710&group_id=240&atid=978), [FR#2120](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2120&group_id=240&atid=978) and [FR#1492](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1492&group_id=240&atid=978)

Answer (score 3):

This is the syntax. `DT` will have to have `x` as a key for it to work.

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=sample(rnorm(9)), v=1:9)
setkey(DT, x)
DT[DT[, list(e=min(y), d=max(y)), by=x]]

   x           y v           e         d
1: a  0.04583602 4 -0.08423764 0.5778324
2: a  0.57783240 5 -0.08423764 0.5778324
3: a -0.08423764 6 -0.08423764 0.5778324
4: b -1.30934873 1 -1.30934873 0.3071819
5: b -0.05972203 2 -1.30934873 0.3071819
6: b  0.30718188 3 -1.30934873 0.3071819
7: c -0.72347616 7 -0.72347616 0.7800817
8: c -0.46930825 8 -0.72347616 0.7800817
9: c  0.78008168 9 -0.72347616 0.7800817
```

Comment: thanks for your solution +1. It works great. Maybe, I was looking for a more intuitive solution, a non-setting key solution, for instance. thanks once again

Comment: Sure. This may not look intuitive at first, but `DT.1[DT.2]` is `data.table` way of merging two `data.table`s. Don't forget to accept the solutions you get!

Comment: @Nestorghh -- If you *really* don't want to use keys, you could do this: `merge(DT, DT[, list(e=min(y), d=max(y)), by="x"], by="x")`.